# React Native: 'React' refers to a umd global but the current file is a module consider adding an import instead

Tags: react-native

I was getting this error while adding a **View** component in **.tsx** file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['React' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64656055/react-refers-to-a-umd-global-but-the-current-file-is-a-module)

Answer (score 47):

I raised this question and answered myself as I thought it will help others who are facing similar issue.

Please import `React` in your code import statements:

```
import * as React from 'react';
```

Reference:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14118

Answer (score 12):

One don't need to import everything using *

It's just react which is missing and needs to be imported so that JSX can be understood.

So just do following

```
import React from 'react';
```

Comment: Except it's not recommended: https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1308739731551858689?s=20&t=2sXKpECWNDoZh5rKDMZJWA

Answer (score 11):

With the introduction of a new JSX transform in React 17, it is no longer necessary to import `React` in every file that uses JSX. If you are using TypeScript, edit the [`jsx` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#jsx) in your `tsconfig` to use `"react-jsx"`.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "jsx": "react-jsx"
    }
}
```

The old default transformation (`"jsx": "react"`), compiled JSX into calls to `React.createElement`, so `React` had to be in scope for it to work. The `react-jsx` transform, however, uses the `_jsx` function and automatically inserts the import for it. After this change, unused imports of `React` can be safely removed.

See also: https://legacy.reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html

Answer (score 2):

Try importing in this way

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
```

Answer (score -2):

Use any of the following to remove the error:

```
declare var React: any;
var React;
import React from "react";
import * as React from "react";
```